# Kotlin - read only first n lines in file

Tags: kotlin

Is there a method, without resolving to traditional Java-like for loops, to limit the number of lines read by BufferedReader?

Take this code for example:

```
bufferedReader.useLines { it }
            .take(10)
            .toList()
```

The documentation for `useLines` states:

> Calls the [block] callback giving it a sequence of all the lines in this file and closes the reader once
>    * the processing is complete.

To my understanding, this means that the **entire file** will be read, and only then the first ten will be filtered out of the sequence. I couldn't find anything online addressing this issue except fetching only the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Sequence` is a lazily evaluated collection. That means only the necessary items will be processed, so if you `take(10)`, only the first 10 lines will be processed.

The keyword in the documentation is thus:

> Calls the [block] callback giving it a **sequence** of all the lines in
>   this file and closes the reader once the processing is complete.

Now `useLines` closes the source as soon as its block is completed, making your code incorrect. Instead, use the following:

```
val list : List<String> = bufferedReader
    .useLines { lines: Sequence<String> ->
        lines
            .take(10)
            .toList()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with useLines